# Link to text PHP

Tags: php, function, preg-replace

I'm already using this which I found on the net, for whenever I want to edit the information and there is already a converted link which is done by adding a new post, I need this to remove the link into text then when it's submitted to be updated, it will use this function to convert it into a link.

```
function Links($text)
{
     $text = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $text); 
     return $text;
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: All the function needs to do is turn `<a ...>text</a>` into `text`?

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strip_tags
strip_tags("test");